# Anime.js animation doesn't work on Next.js 14

Tags: reactjs, next.js, animejs

I have an issue with Anime.js animations in a Next.js project. The animations work in a regular HTML/CSS/JS, but when implemented in Next.js, the animation does't work. There are no console errors.

Here's the code:

```js
'use client'

import anime from 'animejs/lib/anime.es.js'
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

export default function RootPage() {
  const divRef = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    anime({
      tergets: divRef.current,
      translateX: 100,
      direction: 'alternate',
      loop: true
    })
  }, [])

  return <div ref={divRef} style={{
    backgroundColor: '#000000',
    borderRadius: '9999px',
    height: '2rem',
    left: '1rem',
    position: 'absolute',
    top: '1rem',
    width: '2rem'
  }}></div>
}
```